# Cocos2d 3.0 issues after downloading Xcode update

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I downloaded an update of Xcode today. In my cocos2d 3.0 project it shows "unused function 'getBit'",
"unused variable 'action'" and "unused function 'v2fforangle'". I am really confused. Must I download some cocos2d updates or delete/change something?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing's wrong with Xcode, nothing changed in your cocos2d code either. Update just turned on unused functions/variables/etc warnings. If it bothers you, you can turn it off in project settings.